# Go to network share\folder with Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.0

I'm trying to access a network share in PowerShell 5.1 with elevated permissions executing the following command:

```
gi "\\192.168.1.1\data"
```

**I'm recieving the following error:**

```
gi : Cannot find path '\\192.168.1.1\data' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ gi "\\192.168.1.1\data"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\192.168.1.1\data:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
```

The same command can be executed without any problems when I use PowerShell without elevated permissions.

Any tips?

Comment: Do you use a different user account for elevation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/105173/how-to-access-network-shares-from-an-elevated-process-in-windows-7

Comment: Same account. Error only occurs when I execute the command with elevated permissions.

Comment: You didn't specify a drive share.

Comment: To Colyn1337: Really??.....Please read the title, Im not trying to acces a network drive....